# How to encrypt column SQL Server 2016 Always Encrypted ? -Alter Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

It's easy to encrypt column using query in SQL Server 2016 with "Always Encrypted". But we have existing tables. So how to encrypt a column in existing table? I need it using alter query.

I tried following Query

```
alter table testemp alter column ename  add ENCRYPTED WITH (
ENCRYPTION_TYPE = DETERMINISTIC,
ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = CEK_Auto8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this artical [How to configure Always Encrypted in SQL Server 2016 using SSMS, PowerShell and T-SQL](https://www.sqlshack.com/configure-always-encrypted-sql-server-2016-using-ssms-powershell-t-sql/) in the **Configuring Always Encrypted** paragraph it states that

> Defining column encryption on an existing database columns

can be done through `Sql server management studio` or `PowerShell` but **not** with `T-SQL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt columns in existing table using Sql server management studio.

Please check out this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt757096.aspx)

Comment: Can you clarify if this is the only way to accomplish? Can it not be done from T-SQL or .Net data provider?